# inner join on true

Tags: mysql

My table:

```
   abc
+--------+
| letter |
+--------+
| a      |
| b      |
+--------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM abc t1 INNER JOIN abc t2
ON true
```

Result:

```
+--------+--------+
| letter | letter |
+--------+--------+
| a      | a      |
| b      | a      |
| a      | b      |
| b      | b      |
+--------+--------+
```

What does or how does `ON true` do/work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clause after `on` is the condition which is if met, the row will be returned with the result set.
In your example, the condition is always met, so the result is the Cartesian product of the joined tables.

This is similar to saying `ON 1=1`, which is always true.

You will get the same result if you don't add the condition with the inner join.

Comment: I'll add that you would have the same result with `abc t1 JOIN abc t2`

Comment: @DeadEye more like:  `FROM abc t1 CROSS JOIN abc t2`. I know that MySQL parser makes no distinction of `CROSS JOIN` vs. `INNER JOIN` but that is rather sad, to say the least.